# Ethernet interface doesn't get DHCP address after adding bridged interface

Tags: networking, ethernet, dhcp, network-bridge

On an Ubuntu 18.04 machine I found the default netplan configuration in `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
```

I want to add a bridge interface backed by `en0`, so I added that configuration:

```
    bridges:
        br0:
            interfaces: [eno1]
            dhcp4: true
```

After running `sudo netplan apply` the new bridge interface (`br0`) got an IP, but the existing ethernet interface (`en0`) lost it's IP and I can't get it to DHCP a new one.

Even more odd, if I revert the file to its original contents by removing the new `bridges` clause and run `sudo netplan apply` the `br0` interface sticks around and `en0` still doesn't have an address.

Comment: Are you setting up a different MAC address for the bridge?

Comment: No, the entirety of my config is above. They do seem to have different MAC addresses in the output of `ip addr`